Angular CDK Drag and Drop Not Working After Reopening Bottom Sheet
(Solution found. Answered the question down below)
I'm encountering an issue with Angular's CDK Drag and Drop functionality. I have a component that uses a bottom sheet to display 'user cards' in lists, and it allows dragging and dropping users between these lists. The drag-and-drop feature works perfectly the first time I open the bottom sheet.
However, if I dismiss the bottom sheet and then reopen it, dragging a user from one list to another no longer works. Sorting within the same list still works, but moving items between lists fails.
Here is the relevant code:
connectedLists(): string[] {
    return this.filteredUsers.map((_, i) => `cdk-drop-list-${i}`);
  }

  handleDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<UserCardData[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
      const prevIndex = this.filteredUsers.findIndex(team => team.users === event.previousContainer.data);
      const currIndex = this.filteredUsers.findIndex(team => team.users === event.container.data);
  
      if (prevIndex > -1 && currIndex > -1) {
        transferArrayItem(
          this.filteredUsers[prevIndex].users,
          this.filteredUsers[currIndex].users,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );
      }
    } else {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
    this.highlightedListIndex = null;
  }

  handleDragEnter(event: CdkDragEnter<UserCardData[]>): void {
    const index = this.filteredUsers.findIndex(team => team.users === event.container.data);
    this.highlightedListIndex = index;

  }
  
  handleDragLeave(event: CdkDragExit<UserCardData[]>): void {
    this.highlightedListIndex = null;

  }

  cdkDragStarted(event: CdkDragStart): void {
    event.source.element.nativeElement.classList.add('dragging');

  }

  cdkDragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
    event.source.element.nativeElement.classList.remove('dragging');

  }

Component HTML Template
<div class="content relocate" cdkScrollable>
          <div *ngFor="let team of filteredUsers; let i = index" cdkDropListGroup>
            <div class="team-header">
              <h2>{{ team.teamName }}</h2>
              <span class="divider"></span>
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-down chevron" [ngClass]="{'collapsed': team.collapsed}" (click)="toggleCollapse(team)"></i>
            </div>
          
            <div [@collapseExpand]="team.collapsed ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded'" cdkDropList
                 [cdkDropListData]="team.users" 
                 [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedLists()" class="drag-drop-list"
                 [ngClass]="{'highlight': highlightedListIndex === i}"
                 [cdkDropListAutoScrollStep]="10"
                 (cdkDropListEntered)="handleDragEnter($event)" 
                 (cdkDropListExited)="handleDragLeave($event)"
                 (cdkDropListDropped)="handleDrop($event)">
              <div *ngFor="let user of team.users" cdkDrag class="drag-drop-item">
                <app-user-card [userCardData]="user"></app-user-card>
                <div cdkDragHandle class="drag-handle">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-grip-lines"></i>
                </div>
                <div *cdkDragPlaceholder>
                  <app-user-card [userCardData]="user" class="cdk-drag-placeholder"></app-user-card>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

What I've Tried:

Destroying and reinitializing all relevant component state and
instances (Swiper, drag-and-drop lists, and connected lists).
Forcing Angular change detection after reinitializing the
drag-and-drop lists.
Added logging to understand the state and flow of the
initialization process.

Issue:
The drag-and-drop functionality works perfectly the first time the bottom sheet is opened.
Upon dismissing and reopening the bottom sheet, dragging users between lists no longer works, though sorting within the same list still functions.
Help Needed:
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing the drag-and-drop functionality to fail after reopening the bottom sheet?
Is there a more effective way to reinitialize the drag-and-drop lists or manage their state?

I see that you use angular animations (the [@collapseExpand]="team.collapsed ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded'" I suggest try use .css instead of it. NOTE I imagine that you can remove also the part of *cdkDragPlaceholder because it's the same that the drag but I'm not pretty sure. NOTE: Check also if error in console.

@Eliseo I tried removing the animation completely, unfortunately this didn't solve it.
You are right to question the use of *cdkDragPlaceholder, it is indeed redundant.
No errors are present at any time doing the workflow.

Most likely related to the lifecycle of the Angular CDK Drag and Drop component. When you dismiss the bottom sheet the component is likely destroyed but the references to the lists in the Drag and Drop component might still be kept in memory. When you reopen the bottom sheet, a new component is created but the Drag and Drop component might still be using the old references, which are no longer valid.
You could try disconnecting the list from the Drag and Drop component when the bottom sheet is dismissed and then reconnect them when the bottom sheet is reopened.
You can do this by injecting the DragDrop service and calling the disconnectDropList and connectDropList methods.
maybe something like this?
constructor(private dragDrop: DragDrop) { }

ngOnDestroy() {
  // Disconnect the lists when the component is destroyed
  this.filteredUsers.forEach((_, i) => {
    this.dragDrop.disconnectDropList(`cdk-drop-list-${i}`);
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Reconnect the lists when the component is (re)initialized
  this.filteredUsers.forEach((_, i) => {
    this.dragDrop.connectDropList(`cdk-drop-list-${i}`);
  });
}

NOTE: I would also suggest writing some tests to your code to ensure it works as expected.

are the methods you mentioned just hypothetical examples? I ask because I can't find connectDropList or disconnectDropList methods directly in the DragDrop service. However, I'll explore managing the lifecycle of drop list references. Could be that stale references are giving me problems. Thanks.

I found the solution to the problem.
The issue was related to the Id assignment of the 'cdkDropList'.
Explanation
TS:
connectedLists(): string[] {
    return this.filteredUsers.map((_, i) => `cdk-drop-list-${i}`);
  }

HTML:
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedLists()"

The connectedLists() method sets Id's based on the indices of the 'filteredUsers' array.
Which would follow a sequence of:
cdk-drop-list-0 
cdk-drop-list-1 
cdk-drop-list-2
//etc

This happens in the component locally.
Where at the Angular CDK also generates Id's for each 'cdkDropList'.
Following the same sequence of:
cdk-drop-list-0 
cdk-drop-list-1 
cdk-drop-list-2
//etc

But this happens globally.
When I dismiss and reopen the bottomsheet the component and it's previous state was destroyed which results in the connectedLists() method starting over in the sequence of setting the Id's for the list. Following the same pattern as before:
cdk-drop-list-0 
cdk-drop-list-1 
cdk-drop-list-2
//etc

But the CDK, because it's generating the ID's globally, will continue from the previous sequence, generating new Id's, as so:
cdk-drop-list-3 
cdk-drop-list-4 
cdk-drop-list-5
//etc

This obviously causes a mismatch between the Id's in the DOM and the once expected from the drag & drop logic.
I witnessed this when comparing the element tree with what the id's from the connectedLists() method logged in the console.
Solution
Setting the id attribute in the template which results in the cdkDropList getting a consisten ID based on its index, no matter how many times the component is reinitialized.
[id]="'cdk-drop-list-' + i"

